# Why does RTTI seem frowned upon?

Tags: c++

It seems everywhere I read that either a library boasts if not needing RTTI or an article advises against its use. What is so bad about it and why is it such a good thing not to need it?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Because using it usually means you are subverting polymorphism (`if (type is foo) { do this; } else if (type is bar) { do that; } else ...`), which usually means you have engineered yourself into a corner and need to rethink your design.
2. Because authors of C++ compilers put a lot of effort into optimising polymorphic behaviour, but less so into optimising use of RTTI.

Comment: The one place that RTTI could have helped, but did not, is in reflection.  C++ makes serialization, marshaling, and object inspection much harder than it is in other languages because of this.  There are many, many times I've wished that C++ had a decent reflection mechanism...

Comment: @sfstewman: I completely agree; if reflection existed then RTTI would become essential and useful.

Answer (score 2):

C++ allows a lot of static tricks with templates thus reducing the need of RTTI (everything is generic at the compile time, but concrete at the run-time).

On the contra, the "true" (SmallTalk-like) OOP way of dealing with classes requires dynamic binding and RTTI.

C++ allows both, but excessive dynamic_casts and virtual functions may and do degrade performance.

Answer (score 1):

Many stripped down embedded systems will have simpler/smaller implementations that don't support RTTI.  If your library doesn't need it, then you are portable to more systems.

Answer (score 0):

RTTI introduces a bigger role for CRT(C Runtime). C++ developers treasure speed of execution. The last thing one wants is introduction of runtime which would relatively slow the application.

Answer (score -1):

RTTI does something that globally unique ordinals specified at design time can do much better. Two reasons for not using RTTI.

Performance : It is non trivial to come up with a an implementation that scales as well as using ordinals / enums to represent types, and since you don't want namespace collisions you have to use strings, not just strings, globally unique strings. In scripting languages everything is a string inately, thus there is no frowning in these sorts of languages.

Design Elegance : Ordinal based typing works, and if your using it, chances are you had the foresight to design the system properly from the get-go. Such design are pretty much always better than relying on RTTI.

Comment: What is "ordinal based typing"?

Comment: Unique numbers that mean something. Like the entries of an enum.

Comment: By ordinal-based typing, you mean an integer identifier that serves as the class identifier.  This is sometimes useful, but tends to promote awful-looking `switch` statements.  It also makes the very system hard to extend: what happens if two extensions use the same identifier?  RTTI is slightly better in this regard, though not by much.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not convinced that "you can implement RTTI manually" is a great argument against the use of RTTI.

Comment: you don't have to have the switch statements when you can use a TMP library supplying the visitor pattern. Allthough, I have seen RTTI implemented in C based systems and there are generally under a dozen types, and if there are more the model is generally a heirarchical one. In which case your switch statement logic would be implemented across function calls. I think a system with more than a few dozen base types, for which you require RTTI, probably smells of bad design.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a good thing (to not have/use RTTI). Binding should be as late as possible (but not later). Speed and power consumption needs limit you in how late you can bind, but developments in chip technology mean  more and more projects can afford to do later binding. Later binding allows design decisions to be made later, when more information is available allowing better decisions.